# Arranging graphs on one screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wan to four graphs side-by-side linearly but they keep overlapping. I am using d3.js and I would like to draw these four graphs side by side.

I tried drawing each graph in its own svg tag and then combine them but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
          const svg = d3.select("svg");
          const width = +svg.attr("width");
          const height = +svg.attr("height");

          var TelescopeData = [
            { Average: 2000, TelescopeName: "1 meter" },
            { Average: 3000, TelescopeName: "1.9 meter" },
            { Average: 4000, TelescopeName: "Lesedi" }
          ];

          var padding = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 75 };

          const innerWidth = width - padding.left - padding.right;
          const innerHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

          var colors = ["red", "black", "green"];

          var yScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(TelescopeData, d => d.Average)])
            .range([innerHeight, 0])
            .nice();

          var xScale = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(
              TelescopeData.map(d => {
                return d.TelescopeName;
              })
            )
            .range([0, innerWidth])
            .padding(0.4);

          //xAxis
          const xAxis = svg
            .append("g")
            .classed("xAxis", true)
            .attr(
              "transform",
              `translate(${padding.left},${innerHeight + padding.top})`
            )
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

          //yAxis
          const yAxis = svg
            .append("g")
            .classed("yAxis", true)
            .attr("transform", `translate(${padding.left},${padding.top})`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

          // now adding the data

          const rectGrp = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${padding.left},${padding.top})`);
          rectGrp
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(TelescopeData)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", (d, i) => {
              return innerHeight - yScale(d.Average);
            })
            .attr("x", d => {
              return xScale(d.TelescopeName);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
              return yScale(d.Average);
            })
            .attr("fill", (d, i) => {
              return colors[i];
            });
          rectGrp
            .append("text")
            .attr("y", -20)
            .attr("x", 50)
            .text("Quarterly Average");
        </script>
```

I expect to see the code attached here to be used for drawing 3 other graphs side-side with the first one

Comment: This is more of a CSS question. You can achieve it with Grid, or Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to have four graphs shown side by side on the screen next to each other?

That is what your question seems to imply, without having an example of what you want the output to look like.  The other option would be, how to merge four graphs into one graph, which is an entirely different question.

Here is a very simple HTML document that will put the four graphs side by side on the screen.  I think your problem was probably that you were selecting the element to draw to using the SVG selector instead of assigning an id to each different element and then selecting each element id.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function drawGraph(elementId) {
            const svg = d3.select(elementId);
        const width = +svg.attr("width");
        const height = +svg.attr("height");

        let TelescopeData = [
            { Average: 2000, TelescopeName: "1 meter" },
            { Average: 3000, TelescopeName: "1.9 meter" },
            { Average: 4000, TelescopeName: "Lesedi" }
        ];

        let padding = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 75 };

        const innerWidth = width - padding.left - padding.right;
        const innerHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

        let colors = ["red", "black", "green"];

        let yScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(TelescopeData, d => d.Average)])
            .range([innerHeight, 0])
            .nice();

        let xScale = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(
                TelescopeData.map(d => {
                return d.TelescopeName;
                })
            )
            .range([0, innerWidth])
            .padding(0.4);

        //xAxis
        const xAxis = svg
            .append("g")
            .classed("xAxis", true)
            .attr("transform",`translate(${padding.left},${innerHeight + padding.top})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

        //yAxis
        const yAxis = svg
            .append("g")
            .classed("yAxis", true)
            .attr("transform", `translate(${padding.left},${padding.top})`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        // now adding the data

        const rectGrp = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${padding.left},${padding.top})`);
        rectGrp
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(TelescopeData)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", (d, i) => {
                return innerHeight - yScale(d.Average);
            })
            .attr("x", d => {
                return xScale(d.TelescopeName);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.Average);
            })
            .attr("fill", (d, i) => {
                return colors[i];
            });
        rectGrp
            .append("text")
            .attr("y", -20)
            .attr("x", 50)
            .text("Quarterly Average");
    }
    drawGraph("#testsvg1");
    drawGraph("#testsvg2");
    drawGraph("#testsvg3");
    drawGraph("#testsvg4");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="#testsvg1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
    <svg id="#testsvg2" width="200" height="200"></svg>
    <svg id="#testsvg3" width="200" height="200"></svg>
    <svg id="#testsvg4" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```